# TypeError: this is undefined When using Google Maps api with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

**Hello Everyone,**
I am using Google maps javascript api with jQuery and i keep getting this error when ever i call sendData() method:

> ** TypeError: this is undefined main.js:22**

I have tried to use $ instead of jQuery before but same error still shows. i have added the jQuery.noConflict() and still nothing happened!!!

all variables passed in the post are assigned values so i am sending data to my PHP code to store it in the DB.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    var map= null;
    var jQuery= jQuery.noConflict( true );
    var from_name,to_name,from_coord,to_coord, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime, returnFlag, destinationType,destinationName,cost,range;

    function sendData()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/dest_cont/storeDest",
                type : "POST",
                dataType : "json",
                data :  {
                        userEmail:userEmail,
                        from_name: from_name ,
                        to_name:  to_name,
                        from_coord: from_coord ,
                        to_coord:  to_coord, 
                        fromDate: fromDate , 
                        toDate: toDate , 
                        fromTime: fromTime , 
                        toTime:  toTime, 
                        returnFlag:  returnFlag, 
                        destinationType: destinationType ,
                        destinationName: destinationName ,
                        cost:  cost,
                        range: range
                },
                success : function(dataresponse){
                    if(dataresponse == "found"){
                        alert("found"); 
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("none");
                    }
                }

            });

    }
```

Comment: Few things need to be clarified: 1. What does _<?php echo base_url()?>_ print in there? 2. What is on _main.js_ on line 22 since the error comes from there?

Comment: By the way it should be `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: <?php echo base_url()?> this is used to get my url which is working fine and in runtime it brings my server controller page: jQuery.ajax({url : "http://localhost/carpooling/index.php/dest_cont/storeDest"

Comment: main.js is google maps library which is loaded in runtime, http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/4/main.js

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the error.  Including any required HTML/CSS/Javascript (a working code snippet or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that produces the error would be helpful as well)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out,

The issue is: I was sending an object of LatLng type as one the data items of my post request.

I solved it by using .toString() function to turn my coordinates to string so it can be parsed into JSON.

i was going to post a complete script but while doing so, i solved the issue :)

Thanks everyone for trying to help. I appreciate it.